# Why is jvmmonitor memory profiler not listing our classes

Tags: java, memory, profiling

In the past I have used the eclipse plugin from jvmmonitor.org for CPU profiling, but now I am confused as to its memory profiling capability.  Specifically, it is not listing any of our classes.  It is showing primarily primitives, arrays of primitives, java.lang.String, and a few org.hibernate and org.springframework classes.  Is there some configuration of the memory profile that I may need to tweak, because I certainly would expect that our locally written com.* classes would appear in the memory analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely not reading the data quite right.
Certainly the primitives and String(s) specifically are likely to take up the vast majority of the memory.

Your objects might indeed hold references to some of those objects, and in fact caching them, reducing their number of instances by use of Enums, intern()ing frequently used strings, using StringBuilder / StringBuffer instead of String, and not forgetting to null out old references is much more likely to fix any memory problems you have.  Its not likely that adjusting the internals of your code in most instances will help (unless you are allocating large blocks of data in special objects that are for some reason not primitives or arrays - unlikely), without removing those unneeded strings and primitives.

The question then becomes why all these things are in memory?  Can we get rid of them? If so how? Typically by nulling out references, eliminating unnecessary allocations, interning strings, making them available for garbage collection using weak references, not loading them in the first place through lazy initialization, or other strategies (object re-use), static methods instead of instance methods, etc.

From their website: "[JVM Monitor](http://www.jvmmonitor.org/doc/index.html#Starting_Monitoring_JVM) doesn't provide an ability to analyze the references, but instead provide(sic) an ability to generate hprof file, so that you can further analyze the references with other tools like [Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)."  I recommend you consult the documentation there, and also their [blog](http://memoryanalyzer.blogspot.com/).  I will note there are alternative tools for analyzing hprof files.

Comment: This is useful information but I'm looking for specific advice on how to use jvmmonitor to zero in on problem areas.  It's been years since I've used a memory profiler but in my hazy memory I would expect to either limit the classes of interest, or find out where in the code a particular object was allocated, or something like that.  I'm not here to complain about a free tool, just wondering if it has capabilities that I haven't discovered yet.

Comment: I'm afraid that thhat's simply the wrong tool.  JVM Monitor can generate an hprof file though, that can be analyzed to obtain the information you are after.  (See edit above).

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks.  I have found that using jconsole to generate the hprof file and opening it in Eclipse Memory Analyzer works well.

Comment: Good luck with your analyzing!